# Do psp have a pc on it?

Tags: psp

I need a pc to play sims 4 and the one I want is $349 .Someone told me that my psp has a pc.Is that true?The game is really cool and it will take me months to save up and I want to make sure before I start.

Comment: No.  No, it does not.

Comment: Is the Minecraft tag actually just a code for "I want downvotes"? I shudder to think what train of thought could lead you to believe it'd be an appropriate tag here. Probably one operated by British Rail.

Comment: @studoku its the most popular tag, so when someone submits a question without a tag it is the first in list of suggestions.

Comment: this pains me greatly.

Answer (score 3):

While a PSP is technically a computer, it's a completely different kind of computer than your traditional PC or Macintosh. There will be no way of taking a game designed for your PC, and running it on your PSP.